# Select entry from JSP site, delete entry from database with SQL and JBDC

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

I need some help with creating a method that removes an entry/row in my SQL database. I use the JBDC, JSP and java for this. I already have an add method that works with my JSP site. The problem is that my not sure if I need to create an object to make this work. Here's my code JSP so far (removeMatch.jsp):

```
    <div class="content">

    <%
        String databaseId = request.getParameter("id");
        String matchDate = request.getParameter("matchDate");
        String matchTime = request.getParameter("matchTime");
        String meetingTime = request.getParameter("meetingTime");
        String series = request.getParameter("series");
        String opponent = request.getParameter("opponent");
        String matchLocation = request.getParameter("matchLocation");


        if (matchDate != null && matchTime != null && meetingTime != null && series != null && opponent != null && matchLocation != null) {
            int intSeries = Integer.parseInt(series);
            Match match = new Match(matchDate, matchTime, meetingTime, intSeries, opponent, matchLocation);

            //cast string to long value
            long longDatabaseId = Long.parseLong(databaseId);
            match.setDatabaseId(longDatabaseId);

            //remove the match
            MatchMapper.removeMatch(match);

            //Test in console, they don't print the same values that are connected to the databaseId:
                System.out.println(databaseId);
                System.out.println(matchDate);
                System.out.println(matchTime);
                System.out.println(meetingTime);
                System.out.println(series);
                System.out.println(opponent);
                System.out.println(matchLocation);
        }
    %>

    <h3>Vælg de kampe som du vil slette og dermed fjerne fra
        databasen:</h3>
    <form action="removeMatch.jsp" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                <!-- TABEL PASSER IKKE OVER ENS!!!! -->

                    <th></th>
                    <th>Dato</th>
                    <th>Modstander</th>
                    <th>Spilletid</th>
                    <th>Mødetid</th>
                    <th>Spillested</th>
                    <th>Serie</th>
                </tr>
                <%
                    ArrayList<Match> matches = MatchMapper.getAllMatches();
                    for (Match m : matches) {
                %>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="id" value=<%=m.getDatabaseId()%>></td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" name="matchDate" value=<%=m.getDate()%>><%=m.getDate()%></td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" name="matchTime" value=<%=m.getMatchStart()%>><%=m.getMatchStart()%></td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" name="meetingTime" value=<%=m.getMeetingTime()%>><%=m.getMeetingTime()%></td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" name="series" value=<%=m.getSeries()%>><%=m.getSeries()%></td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" name="opponent" value=<%=m.getOpponent()%>><%=m.getOpponent()%></td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" name="matchLocation" value=<%=m.getLocation()%>><%=m.getLocation()%></td>
                </tr>
                <%
                    }
                %>
            </table>

            <a href="matchTable.jsp"><input type="submit" value="Slet Kampe" /></a>

        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

The idea is that the user checks off the rows that he wants to delete, and then a method from another java file removes the row in the database (removeMatch() @ MatchMapper.java):

```
    public static void removeMatch(Match match) {
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        con = JDBCConnectionFactory.getInstance().getNewConnection();
        // creates empty string
        String sql = "";
        // if Match  exists in database, then prepare to call
        // a DELETE FROM table_name WHERE some_column=some_value statement (matchDate and opponent)
        if (match.isInDatabase()) {
            sql = "DELETE FROM matches WHERE ID = ?) "
                    + "VALUES (?)";
        }
        // if Match doesn't exist in database, then prepare to make an
        // return 
        else {
            System.out.println("Kamp findes ikke i databasen");
        }

        PreparedStatement prep = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        prep.setLong(1, match.getDatabaseId());
        // if the match already exists in database, then get the id (so it
        // won't create a new id)
        if (match.isInDatabase()) {
            prep.setLong(2, match.getDatabaseId());
        }
        // execute insert/update
        prep.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        JDBCConnectionFactory.getInstance().closeConnection(con);
    }

}
```

I can get the right databaseId but my test prints to the console keeps on printing the values for the row with the databaseId "1". There probably is a way to pass the correct values, but I can't figure it out. The other problem is that the removeMatch doesn't remove the match, in fact, it doesn't make any changes to the database whatsoever.

Comment: Having scriptlets in JSP is bad practice. You may consider alternatives like JSTL.

Comment: Why not use MVC pattern? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: I know that its considered bad practice, but this is a school assignment :/

Comment: In the future, if you're asking for help on school assignments, you should tag it with the `homework` tag.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your DELETE sql looks wrong:

```
sql = "DELETE FROM matches WHERE ID = ?) " // Why is there a closing parenthesis?
          + "VALUES (?)";      // Why are you using VALUES in a DELETE?
```

I would just use

```
sql = "DELETE FROM matches WHERE ID = ? ";
```

This will remove the need for these lines:

```
if (match.isInDatabase()) {
    prep.setLong(2, match.getDatabaseId());
}
```

Finally, to fix your problem of getting no changes to the database, I would end your `try` block with this:

```
con.commit();
```

This may not be necessary if you have autocommit set to `true`. I don't mean to criticize you, but it seems like this is your first time writing JDBC code. If that's the case, I'd highly recommend going through [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html). It gives you all of the basic explanations of JDBC principles.